# How to fix Fixed Sidebar After Scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this problem trying to attempt a sidebar fixed after scrolling.

After the `posScroll` is bigger than the `sidebar` offset, the class that I want to maintain fixed keeps on going back to its original position then where I want it to be, how should I fix this?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var posScroll = $(window).scrollTop();


    var sidebar = $('.noticias-search').offset().top;
    console.log(sidebar,posScroll);

    if( posScroll  > sidebar) {
        $('.noticias-search').addClass('sidebar-fixed');
    }else{
        $('.noticias-search').removeClass('sidebar-fixed');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
var sidebar = $('.noticias-search').height();

function stickySearch(){
    var posScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if( posScroll  > sidebar) {
        $('.noticias-search').addClass('sidebar-fixed');
    }else{
        $('.noticias-search').removeClass('sidebar-fixed');
    }
} 

$(window).scroll(function() {

    stickySearch();

});
```

The sidebar height is a fixed value (I assume), you measure it's height, then you are comparing that height to your `scrollTop()` offset. If it's bigger, then you get the class, if not, the class is removed.

Try it and see if it works.

Also add some html to your question.